# When would you want the primary key to be indexed with other columns?

Tags: mysql

At work we have a table where the primary key is being used as the third column of a three way index. I do not have an intimate understanding of indices so this use case confuses me. If a primary key is both unique and already indexed, what good does it serve to have an extra index that is only useful if the query includes the primary key, which is already uniquely indexed?

Comment: is the clustered index on the primary key column alone?

Comment: There may be some queries those where criteria, group by clause, and / or order by clause use these 3 fields, thus the multi-column index can be used to speed the query even more up. Quite common situation.

Comment: I'm not sure what a clustered index is.

Comment: @Shadow I understand that for non unique indexed columns, but if one of the 3 fields is a unique indexed column, I don't see how it can provide any extra benefit? Unless my understanding of indexing is way off.

Comment: Then your understanding of indexes is a way off :)

Comment: Seems that way. My assumption was that indexing meant pointing you directly to the record(s) that match your indexed field's value. So with that belief it seemed like indexing the primary key in a multi-column index would be redundant. The only way I can think of that would make it not redundant would be if an index worked like a hash table with collisions and all, and thus having another 3 column index would produce a different hashing allocation (speeding it up by intersecting these hash lookups). Am I getting closer?...

Answer (score 0):

In certain situations having a single primary index key need not necessary be optimal for your queries. Like in situations involving multiple searches with frequently used multiple columns. In these cases it makes sense to use these multiple columns in defining indexes. So that these additional indexes may be used in ideal queries for better data retrieval.

Try this article it has more info with some examples http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html